# jPlayer - Flash fallback takes 30x longer to begin playback than the HTML5 version of the same video does

Tags: jplayer

Trying to set up jPlayer with an HTML5 video, and also a Flash fallback for the same video.

The HTML5 video playback is lightning fast (only about 1 second "buffer" time)!

The issue I'm having though is with the Flash fallback. That same exact video that begins playback in 1 second with the HTML5 version, takes 50+ seconds to begin playback with the Flash version (and I'm on a 1.5 Mbps DSL connection). And during all this time, there is no "progress" bar at all... just a black screen.

It's almost as if it's trying to download the entire video before it begins playback. I have tested this in Firefox, Chrome, IE9, IE8, and IE7. Same thing in all browsers. And the Flash player is up to date in all browsers. Also, I always clear my browser's cache between each test, so that I can be sure each test is accurate.

Any ideas what might cause this?

I have tried a lot of different video encoders... Sony Vegas, Handbrake, Miro, Super, Freemake, Any Video Converter, yet I get more/less the same result with each one (instant playback when using HTML5 video, but a VERY long buffer time when using the Flash fallback).

So then I thought maybe there's a MIME issue with my server, so I added the following code to my .htaccess file in the root directory...

```
    # AddType TYPE/SUBTYPE EXTENSION  
    AddType audio/mpeg mp3
    AddType audio/mp4 m4a
    AddType audio/ogg ogg
    AddType audio/ogg oga
    AddType audio/webm webma
    AddType audio/wav wav
    AddType video/mp4 mp4
    AddType video/mp4 m4v
    AddType video/ogg ogv
    AddType video/webm webm
    AddType video/webm webmv
```

But that didn't make any difference.

Then as a test, I downloaded the "Big Buck Bunny" videos (m4v, ogv, webm) from the jPlayer server, and uploaded them to my server, and to my surprise, even the Flash version played back instantly! (within 1 second). Very strange.

So then for another test, I re-encoded the Big Buck Bunny videos to mp4/m4v using every encoder I have (Sony Vegas, Handbrake, Miro, Super, Freemake, Any Video Converter), uploaded all of those files to my server, then tested the Flash fallback with each of those files individually. And with every single one, it took a long time for Flash playback to begin (even the ones that I encoded to super small file sizes). Yet all of the HTML5 versions still played back instantly.

I am truly stuck as to what's causing the Flash fallback to take so long to begin playback. Over the past few days, I have tried every possible test I could think of to pinpoint the problem, but still cannot figure it out.

Any ideas?

If it helps, below is one of the pages that I am using to test this. On that particular page, I am using the exact same HTML code from one of the jPlayer demos, and I set the default solution to "flash". Only thing different is that I have re-encoded the m4v file, in order to demonstrate the Flash delay (which is about 30 seconds on my end, for this particular video)...

http://thebestinfo.org/jplayer/flash.html

And like I mentioned above, no matter what encoder I use, or how small I compress the file, there's always a huge delay when using the Flash fallback.

I would be so grateful for any help in figuring this out! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jPlayer dev guide's server response](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-server-response) section, the behavior you're describing may be caused either by a server's failure to accept byte range requests or a lack of media length metadata in the file header.

> ### Byte-Range Requests
>
> Your server must enable Range requests. This is easy to check for by seeing if your server's response includes the Accept-Ranges in its header. Most HTML5 browsers enable seeking to new file positions during a download, so the server must allow the new Range to be requested.
>
> Failure to accept byte Range requests will cause problems on some HTML5 browsers. Often the duration cannot be read from the file as some formats require that the start and end of the file is read to know its duration. Chrome tends to be the browser that has most problems if the Range request is not enabled on the server, but all browsers will have some issue even if it is only that you have to wait for all the media to load before jumping close to the end.
>
> This problem is known to affect Jetty 6 servers with their default configuration.
>
> A PHP function has been written by the jPlayer community that can serve media files with support for Range requests. See this [jPlayer Support Group Post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jplayer/nSM2UmnSKKA/bC-l3k0pCPMJ) on the topic.

Comment: If I am using flash player of jplayer then also Byte-Range Requests is supported?